# Not truly Random

Tags: c++, random

For some reason the code I'm about to post below is not purely random... And I have used `srand()`, to attempt to make it random.. I don't know why it's acting weird...

```
#include<vector>
#include "../Header Files/SinglePlayer.h"

SinglePlayer::SinglePlayer()
{

}

int myRand(int low, int high) 
{
   srand(time(NULL));
   return rand() % (high - low + 1) + low;
}

void SinglePlayer::startGame()
{
    cout << "Starting Single Player........." << endl;
    cout << "Starting out with two cards...." << endl;
    int randomCardStarterOnePlayer = myRand(0,10);
    int randomCardStarterTwoPlayer = myRand(0,10);
    int randomCardStarterOneAI = myRand(0,10);
    int randomCardStarterTwoAI = myRand(0,10);
    this -> calculateRandomStarter(randomCardStarterOnePlayer,
                                   randomCardStarterTwoPlayer,
                                   randomCardStarterOneAI,
                                   randomCardStarterTwoAI);
    cout << "You Start out with " << amountPlayer << endl;
    cout << "Computer Starts out with " << amountAI << endl;
}

void SinglePlayer::calculateRandomStarter(int randomOnePlayer, int randomTwoPlayer, int randomOneAI, int randomTwoAI)
{
    amountPlayer = amountPlayer + randomOnePlayer + randomTwoPlayer;
    playerCards.push_back(randomOnePlayer);
    playerCards.push_back(randomTwoPlayer);

    amountAI = amountAI + randomOneAI + randomTwoAI;
    AICards.push_back(randomOneAI);
    AICards.push_back(randomTwoAI);
}

SinglePlayer::~SinglePlayer()
{
}
```

Outcome:

> ~~~~~~~~~~BLACKJACK~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> Do you want to play single player, or multiplayer? (Enter 0 for single
>   player, 1 for multiplayer)
>
> 0
>
> Starting Single Player.........
>
> Starting out with two cards....
>
> You Start out with 2
>
> Computer Starts out with 2

You can see the player and computer starts with same number.. and that always happens for some reason... I cant seem to spot the problem, please help.

Comment: Put your srand call into the constructor and remove it from myRand. Then try again.

Comment: Did that and tried to execute three times @MartinEttl they stil have same result.. I wouldnt understand why putting in constructor would change it.. :P

Comment: Of course, you have to ensure that srand() is called once before you call rand().

Comment: @MartinEttl that dosent work....

Comment: By the way, please reduce your sample code!

Comment: @MartinEttl the anwser works.. BUT when you try to run it multiple times by doing ./main.out , it gives me the same result as previous round...

Comment: Please check this [minimal example on ideone](http://ideone.com/Fny2AQ): try running the code multiple times (to do this, fork the code) in short and in longer successions: you may get the same random number in short intervals, but you shouldn't get the same number by chance with longer intervals.

Comment: @BeyelerStudios but when i change your code to multiple random integers being made, it gets corrupted... http://cpp.sh/6meex  . thats my problem

Comment: you're still `srand`-ing multiple times, you didn't listen at all to the other commenters: [here's the fix](http://cpp.sh/9unmc)

Comment: @BeyelerStudios your the hero!

Answer (score 3):

`time(NULL)` returns time in seconds, and because you set new seed every time you are generating new number you probably (in most cases) set same number as seed every time.
Move:

```
srand(NULL)
```

to start of main or somewhere where it will be called only once.

Comment: Ok this works and makes computer and player diffrent. BUT when you try to rerun it by doing ./main.out , it gives you the same result as previous round... How do i fix that now?

Comment: Don't run it twice within one second

Comment: 20 seconds still dosent fix it @user4581301 :( .

Comment: That's odd. You may have wandered into weird. This question is nicely resolved, and should work. I recommend a new question with your current code, your test conditions, and your outputs. Anything you do to minimize your test case without eliminating the weird will be both appreciated--very hard to solve weirds without all of the code and too much code leaves plenty of room for multiple bugs to gang up on you--and educational for you. Often minimizing seeking ways to reduce a problem to its barest essentials shows you how to solve the problem.

Comment: But if i ask new question @user4581301 stackoverflow members will say its a duplicate of this question..

Comment: Possibly, but if you word it right, reference this question, and highlight the differences--had `srand` here moved it there, now have a different problem--you should be fine. You do have a different problem. And like I said, if you strip out all of the non-essential stuff and still have and cannot find the bug, you're going to have a very different looking question next time around.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `time(NULL)` in your code returns something that is constant and does not call `std::time(NULL)` as you may expect. If it did, you would have a random number properly generated from `rand()`.

Try to print the output of `time(NULL)` and check if you actually get the number of seconds elasped since the epoch. If not, make sure you include `<ctime>` and call fully qualified `srand(std::time(NULL))`.

Comment: srand(std::time(NULL)) still dosent do it... Is this like a hard question or something?

Comment: can you please print the output from `std::time(NULL)` and see if you get an integer increasing every second.

Comment: shrike its `1463522348` when i run `std::time(NULL)`, not `std:time(NULL)`

Comment: @Universe: then, if you print output of your function `myRand(0, 10)`, you should get a random number properly generated in the appopriate range; I compiled your code and that's what I get.

Comment: shrike... can we do this here? https://ide.c9.io/antihuman/fornoreason#openfile-README.md  Because thats where im actually working the game on.. and if we could fix it there it would be much easier... For me now its not working..